# FX backtesting in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is for a primer course of backtesting FX strategy using PostgreSQL for some technical folks.

Backtesting logic can be implemented pretty easily in a Python or something, but I need to use SQL for this one.

**Input Tables**

I have 2 input tables

1. Buy/sell signals

[image: Buy_Sell_Signals]

2. FX Rates

[image: FX_Rates]

**Backtesting Method:**

I backtest a FX strategy for the period 2019-01-07 to 2019-02-15 (7th Jan to 15th Feb 2019).

To keep the backtesting simple, I have the following simple logic (buy / selling is 100k only).

- Start with 100k holding on 2019-01-01 (1st Jan 2019)
- At  every buy signal:

  - If you hold 100k, do nothing
  - If you hold 0, buy 100k
- At every sell signal

  - If you hold 0, do nothing
  - If you hold 100k, sell 100k

**Expected Output:**

The expected output at the end of backtesting is below:

[image: Expected Outcome]

Field Rules:

- open_bal(t) = close_bal(t-1)
- fx_inv_rate - is the rate at which the
  position was bought fx_inv_rate(t) : if (amt_bot (t-1) > 0) THEN
  fx_inv_rate(t) = fx_curr_rate(t-1) ELSE fx_inv_rate(t) =
  fx_inv_rate(t-1)
- fx_curr_rate - The current fx_rate from FX_Rates table
- amt_bot: if (signal = buy AND open_bal = 0) THEN 100,000 ELSE 0
- amt_sold: if (signal = sell AND open_bal = 100,000) THEN 100,000 ELSE
  0
- close_bal = open_bal + amt_bot - amt_sold
- realized_gain_loss = amt_sold*(fx_curr_rate - fx_inv_rate)/fx_curr_rate)

**What I have done so far:**

Merge the buy/sell signals and fx rates table to get the fields
date_time
fx_curr_rate
signal

Beyond this step I am at a loss of how to code the sequence of steps in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH RECURSIVE backtesting(date_time, curr_pair, open_bal, fx_inv_rate, fx_curr_rate, signal, amt_bot, amt_sold, close_bal, realized_gain_or_loss, is_relevant) AS (
    SELECT date_time,
        curr_pair,
        100000,
        fx_rate,
        fx_rate,
        'OPEN',
        0,
        0,
        100000,
        0::double precision,
        True
    FROM fx.rates
    WHERE curr_pair = 'USDJPY' AND date_time = '2019-01-01'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT (backtesting.date_time + interval '1 day')::date,
        rates.curr_pair,
        close_bal,
        CASE
            WHEN backtesting.amt_bot > 0 THEN fx_curr_rate
            ELSE fx_inv_rate
        END,
        rates.fx_rate,
        CASE
            WHEN (backtesting.date_time + interval '1 day')::date = '2019-02-15' THEN 'CLOSE'
            ELSE COALESCE(signals.signal, backtesting.signal)
        END,
        CASE
            WHEN signals.signal = 'buy' AND backtesting.signal = 'sell' THEN 100000
            ELSE 0
        END,
        CASE
            WHEN signals.signal = 'sell' AND backtesting.signal != 'sell' THEN 100000
            ELSE 0
        END,
        close_bal 
            + CASE WHEN signals.signal = 'buy' AND backtesting.signal = 'sell' THEN 100000 ELSE 0 END
            - CASE WHEN signals.signal = 'sell' AND backtesting.signal != 'sell' THEN 100000 ELSE 0 END,
        (rates.fx_rate - (CASE WHEN backtesting.amt_bot > 0 THEN fx_curr_rate ELSE fx_inv_rate END))/rates.fx_rate
            * (CASE WHEN signals.signal = 'sell' AND backtesting.signal != 'sell' THEN 100000 ELSE 0 END),
        signals.signal IS NOT NULL
    FROM backtesting
        LEFT JOIN fx.rates ON backtesting.date_time + interval '1 day' = rates.date_time AND backtesting.curr_pair = rates.curr_pair
        LEFT JOIN fx.signals ON rates.date_time = signals.date_time AND rates.curr_pair = signals.curr_pair
    WHERE backtesting.signal IS DISTINCT FROM 'CLOSE')
SELECT date_time, curr_pair, open_bal, fx_inv_rate, fx_curr_rate, signal, amt_bot, amt_sold, close_bal,
    round(realized_gain_or_loss::numeric, 0) AS realized_gain_or_loss
FROM backtesting
WHERE is_relevant OR signal = 'CLOSE'
```

EDIT: Just read of recursive common table expressions for the first time. This makes the query so much more adjustable for other strategies. Still the crucial field rules are:

- amt_bot: IF (signal(t) = buy AND signal(t-1) = sell) THEN 100,000 ELSE 0
- amt_sold: IF (signal(t) = sell AND signal(t-1) != sell) THEN 100,000 ELSE 0